# RuntimeException when trying to use Tess4J in Java EE

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, tesseract, tess4j

Im trying to use Tess4J in Java EE (Payara server), is this possible and if so how?

Exact Exception I'm getting:

e = (net.sourceforge.tess4j.TesseractException) net.sourceforge.tess4j.TesseractException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Need to install JAI Image I/O package.
https://java.net/projects/jai-imageio/

I have added the `jai-imageio` to my *pom.xml*, as well as added it to the modules of Payara.

File **pom.xml**

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.tess4j/tess4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version> <!-- used 3.4.2 as well -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.jai-imageio/jai-imageio-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>  <!-- tried without this as well -->
    </dependency>
```

Added JAR to

```
`Payara\glassfish\modules`
```

Tess4J code (If any improvements can be made to this as well it would be appreciated).

```
       ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();
        instance.setDatapath(pLangaugePath); // C:\\t
        instance.setLanguage(pLanguage); // eng

            try {
                File[] tifFiles = PdfUtilities.convertPdf2Png(pFile);

                if (tifFiles != null) {

                    for (File tifFile : tifFiles) {
                        String ocrText = instance.doOCR(tifFile);

                        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(ocrText)) {
                            ret.append(ocrText);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (TesseractException e) {
                LOG.error("Could not do ocr on image file created via pdf ", e);
            }
```

Have tried the following 2 examples as well.
1.

```
     try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pFile)) {
                int totalPages = document.getNumberOfPages();

                PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);

                for (int pi = 0; pi < totalPages; pi++) {
                    BufferedImage image = renderer.renderImageWithDPI(pi, 75);

                    String ocrText = instance.doOCR(image);

                    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(ocrText)) {
                        ret.append(ocrText);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error("Could not do ocr on pdf", e);
            }
```

2.

```
 try {

        ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();
        instance.setDatapath(pLangaugePath); // C:\\t
        instance.setLanguage(pLanguage); // eng

        String ocrText = instance.doOCR(pFile);

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(ocrText)) {
            ret.append(ocrText);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Could not do ocr on image file created via pdf ", e);
    }
```

Research:

Found this [Didnt work / solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590329/unsupported-image-format-may-need-to-install-jai-image-i-o-package)

as well as [didnt work](https://sourceforge.net/p/tess4j/discussion/1202294/thread/f77a57ed/)

Comment: Do you have a development and deployment environment? Is the library installed in deployment as well?

Comment: Yes it is as far as i can see, can you expand on how i can check it exactly, please?

Comment: Have you tried with the sample files in the "Tess4J-3.4.3-src\Tess4J\test\resources\test-data" folder?

Comment: @Daefect91 No i have not, will try it now thanks.

Comment: @Daefect91 Same issue when using test data

Comment: Strange, I just did a quick test on my machine. I created a maven project, added the dependency for tess4j, added the tessdata folder to my project and popped some files in there to test with and it works fine. No complaints about the jai-imagio dependency. Perhaps one of your other dependencies are clashing with tess4j?

Comment: @Daefect91 This can be the case, will try it from a clean project

Comment: @TinusJackson Great, let me know what it does.

Comment: @Daefect91 Created new mvn prject but seems to be doing nothing , debugged it and doesnt throw error?

Comment: If you work on PDF files, make sure GhostScript is installed and in system path.

Comment: @nguyenq Are GhostScript required ? PDF works on a normal java application, problem is that i'm struggling to get it to work with a web app running in a container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tess4J was known for not working with Glassfish due to the run-time exception caused by the unavailability of JNA `RESOURCE_PREFIX` string constant. This issue has been fixed in the latest releases 3.4.9 (for Tesseract 3.05.01) and 4.0.2 (for Tesseract 4.0.0-beta.1). The library can now be used with Glassfish, and perhaps Payara Server.

You may also need to include `ImageIO.scanForPlugins();` statement before the OCR call. That is meant to ensure the appropriate `ImageReader` be available to read input images.